# Assigning components to variables in Unity, benefits?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm wondering if it's beneficial to assign components to variables in Unity C#, as follows

```
public class SceneLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameStatus gameStatus;

    private void Start()
    {
        gameStatus = FindObjectOfType<GameStatus>();    
    }

    public void LoadFirstScene()
    {
        gameStatus.DestroyGame();
    }
}
```

Whereas the shorter version would be without initialising the object as a variable, besides readability are there benefits to using one way or the other?

````
public class SceneLoader : MonoBehaviour
{

    public void LoadFirstScene()
    {
        FindObjectOfType<GameStatus>().DestroyGame();   
    }

}
```
````

Comment: When would you rather pay the cost of searching for this object? At start-up or on scene load? Or would you prefer to avoid the search cost entirely?

Comment: How could I avoid the search cost entirely? As I see it now I only see the start-up or scene load option

Comment: Expose your variable publicly, or private but serialized, so you can assign the reference in your inspector at edit time. No searching at runtime then.

Comment: So everything you assign in SerializableField is calculated beforehand, thus increases performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use of member variables is called caching. It's a space-time trade-off: we use a little extra memory (space) to save ourselves the computation work (time) needed to produce the value from scratch every time.

For something like a reference variable, the memory cost is trivial, so this is a very efficient trade-off to make, if it helps you avoid repeatedly paying a computation cost, or shift that cost to a more convenient moment.

You'll often see it used in cases like this, where we have a homing projectile or enemy that wants to move toward the player every simulation step:

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    var player = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>();

    body.velocity = (player.transform.position - transform.position).normalized * speed;
}
```

Here we're spending time in every physics step to search through all our game objects to find the player object - even though we just did that same search last physics step!

[As the Unity docs say](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BestPracticeUnderstandingPerformanceInUnity7.html),

> It is a general best practice to eliminate all usage of `Object.Find` and `Object.FindObjectOfType` in production code. As these APIs require Unity to iterate over all GameObjects and Components in memory, they rapidly become non-performant as the scope of a project grows.

So for a case like this, it's recommended to limit your searching: say, do it just once and remember the result for subsequent frames:

```
Transform target;

void Start() {
    target = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>().transform;
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    body.velocity = (target.position - transform.position).normalized * speed;
}
```

Now we pay the search cost only once, rather than every physics step.

Or better yet, if we can read a reference to our target from a manager/singleton (global variable), or have it passed to us on initialization from a class that already knows our target via eg. a `SetTarget(Transform target)` method (dependency injection), we can avoid ever searching for it at all. :)

In your particular example, the search is occurring only once anyway. All that's different is whether you're doing that search when this script starts up (eg. when the scene it's in loads), or when it needs to do its work (when the next scene transition happens).

Often a lot of scripts will be doing their setup or searching for their dependencies in `Start()`, so deferring this search until later - so you don't need a `Start()` call on this object - might help you reduce the performance hitch you see when first loading a scene.

But in this case you might have an even better option. It looks like both the `SceneLoader` script and the `GameStatus` script exist in the same scene file. If that's the case, you can expose your `gameStatus` variable to be populated in the Inspector when you're authoring the scene:

```
public GameStatus gameStatus;

// or

[SerializeField] private GameStatus _gameStatus;
```

Now just like before you don't need a `Start()` method, *and* you also don't need to search for this reference when it's time to use it. It's been pre-populated for you at edit time, and it's a quick copy operation for the deserializer to fill in the variable when your scene loads.